# Can SQL Server 2019 use Windows authentication with AWS Simple AD?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, active-directory

Can SQL Server 2019 Standard authenticate users using AWS Simple AD, or is Microsoft AD required?

Comment: I don't see why not. You should be able to validate this yourself for a couple of dollars and not too much time though (spin up a Simple AD instance, spin up a SQL instance, join it to your domain, try to log in).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL server 2019 to authenticate users from AWS AD. I recommend you to go through this [document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/introducing-aws-directory-service-for-microsoft-active-directory-standard-edition/).

Comment: I've seen the referenced document, and that this service can provide authorization services to SQL server is well understood. My question is can auth also be provided by Simple AD, or Is your answer meant to imply that AWS_AD4MS *_IS_* required?